# how to access multidimensional array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to grab out the "teams" array and pull out data such as teamId, etc from it. I was wondering if any of you had any tips/help with this. I have used datas.map(data=>()) but it would not allow me to grab from teams, or maybe im doing it wrong and there is another way to map out a multidimensional array?

```
{
    "gameId": 3226262256,
    "platformId": "NA1",
    "gameCreation": 1575583791449,
    "gameDuration": 1526,
    "queueId": 400,
    "mapId": 11,
    "seasonId": 13,
    "gameVersion": "9.23.299.3089",
    "gameMode": "CLASSIC",
    "gameType": "MATCHED_GAME",
    "teams": [
        {
            "teamId": 100,
            "win": "Fail",
            "firstBlood": true,
            "firstTower": false,
            "firstInhibitor": false,
            "firstBaron": false,
            "firstDragon": false,
            "firstRiftHerald": false,
            "towerKills": 1,
            "inhibitorKills": 0,
            "baronKills": 0,
            "dragonKills": 2,
            "vilemawKills": 0,
            "riftHeraldKills": 0,
            "dominionVictoryScore": 0,
            "bans": [
                {
                    "championId": 111,
                    "pickTurn": 1
                },
                {
                    "championId": 25,
                    "pickTurn": 2
                },
                {
                    "championId": 24,
                    "pickTurn": 3
                },
                {
                    "championId": 235,
                    "pickTurn": 4
                },
                {
                    "championId": 238,
                    "pickTurn": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "teamId": 200,
            "win": "Win",
            "firstBlood": false,
            "firstTower": true,
            "firstInhibitor": true,
            "firstBaron": true,
            "firstDragon": true,
            "firstRiftHerald": true,
            "towerKills": 9,
            "inhibitorKills": 2,
            "baronKills": 1,
            "dragonKills": 1,
            "vilemawKills": 0,
            "riftHeraldKills": 1,
            "dominionVictoryScore": 0,
            "bans": [
                {
                    "championId": 266,
                    "pickTurn": 6
                },
                {
                    "championId": 89,
                    "pickTurn": 7
                },
                {
                    "championId": 64,
                    "pickTurn": 8
                },
                {
                    "championId": -1,
                    "pickTurn": 9
                },
                {
                    "championId": 141,
                    "pickTurn": 10
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

Then here is the code I am trying to use it in:

```
import React from 'react';
import './MatchHistory.css';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';

const MatchData = ({ datas }) => {


  return (
        <div>    
            <Card>
              <h5 className="card-title">Full Match data test Pull...</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Lane:{datas.platformId}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title">MapId:{datas.mapId}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Mode: {datas.gameMode}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Duration: {datas.gameDuration}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">SeasonId: {datas.seasonId}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Version: {datas.gameVersion}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Type: {datas.gameType}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Team Data: players, bans, etc</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Participant info: champ, KDA, etc</h5>
            </Card>  
      </div> 
   )
}

      export default MatchData;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is generally nothing wrong with your code, and the way you are accessing the data to be rendered on your component. If you would like to iterate through `teams` and render it, it will not work if you do something like `datas.map(data=>(...))`, as this will iterate through the entire `datas` object.

Instead, what you should be doing is to do `datas.team.map(data => ...)`, which will allow you to iterate through the values within `team` property using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which works on arrays.

```
import React from 'react';
import './MatchHistory.css';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';

const MatchData = ({ datas }) => {


  return (
        <div>    
            <Card>
              <h5 className="card-title">Full Match data test Pull...</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Lane:{datas.platformId}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title">MapId:{datas.mapId}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Mode: {datas.gameMode}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Duration: {datas.gameDuration}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">SeasonId: {datas.seasonId}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Version: {datas.gameVersion}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Type: {datas.gameType}</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Team Data: {
                datas.team.map(data => {
                  return <div> 
                    // other properties and values within each object in `team`
                  <div>
                })
              }</h5>
              <h5 className="card-title">Participant info: champ, KDA, etc</h5>
            </Card>  
      </div> 
   )
}

export default MatchData;
```

Comment: Hi, when i try this, its giving me the error, cannot read 'map' of undefined. I know it exists in my array cause i have console.logged it but i cant figure out why its doing this

Comment: @FaithElliott is `datas` asynchronous by any chance? Is it from some HTTP request?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj = {"gameId":3226262256,"platformId":"NA1","gameCreation":1575583791449,"gameDuration":1526,"queueId":400,"mapId":11,"seasonId":13,"gameVersion":"9.23.299.3089","gameMode":"CLASSIC","gameType":"MATCHED_GAME","teams":[{"teamId":100,"win":"Fail","firstBlood":true,"firstTower":false,"firstInhibitor":false,"firstBaron":false,"firstDragon":false,"firstRiftHerald":false,"towerKills":1,"inhibitorKills":0,"baronKills":0,"dragonKills":2,"vilemawKills":0,"riftHeraldKills":0,"dominionVictoryScore":0,"bans":[{"championId":111,"pickTurn":1},{"championId":25,"pickTurn":2},{"championId":24,"pickTurn":3},{"championId":235,"pickTurn":4},{"championId":238,"pickTurn":5}]},{"teamId":200,"win":"Win","firstBlood":false,"firstTower":true,"firstInhibitor":true,"firstBaron":true,"firstDragon":true,"firstRiftHerald":true,"towerKills":9,"inhibitorKills":2,"baronKills":1,"dragonKills":1,"vilemawKills":0,"riftHeraldKills":1,"dominionVictoryScore":0,"bans":[{"championId":266,"pickTurn":6},{"championId":89,"pickTurn":7},{"championId":64,"pickTurn":8},{"championId":-1,"pickTurn":9},{"championId":141,"pickTurn":10}]}]}

Array(obj).forEach(item => {
    item.teams.forEach(team => {
        console.log("Team ID: " + team.teamId, team)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have nested array

```
{
.
.
teams--
      |
      bans--
           | 
}
```

try this

```
 <h5 className="card-title">
    Team Data: players, bans, etc
    <ul>
      {datas.teams.map((team, i) => {
        return (
          <li key={i}>
            teamId:{team.teamId}//or other fields inside team
            <ul>
              {team.bans.map((ban, i) => {
                return <li key={i}>championId:{ban.championId}</li> //or other fields inside ban
              })}
            </ul>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  </h5>
```

Working [Codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-feather-cv1di?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)